# how can I set custom _id for a document in mongo-DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to upload a data to mongodb and set a custom id for content in a file which is a sub-document in the collection--

```
{
   _id: document id...,
   FirstName: ...,
   LasrName: ...,
   Email: ...,
   files: [
       content: [
           _id: objectId(...)
       ]
    ],   
}
```

Comment: In such case you can provide your own value to the `_id` field. If you don''t provide the field/value MongoDB will insert it with the `ObjectId`. Your own value can be of any data type, except an array.

Comment: https://github.com/ai/nanoid#:~:text=_id%3A%20%27id%27%20%2B%20nanoid()%2C%0A%20%20%E2%80%A6%0A%7D)-,Mongoose,-const%20mySchema%20%3D%20new

Just add a default value in schema as shown in example

Answer (score 0):

you can set a custom Id for the creation of data by using this schema here. nanoid is rundom string.

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid()  /// random_string
  }
})
```